# How to add auto-generated slick code to classpath

Tags: scala, slick, slick-codegen

I generated source code using the method described here

https://github.com/slick/slick-codegen-example/blob/master/build.sbt

This method works and now when I do `compile` I can see that the auto-generated Target.scala file is being successfully compiled as Tables.class

[image]

but in my source code, If I try to import the autogenerated class file. it says `cannot resolve symbol demo`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by `IntelliJ` can't recognize the generated code, you can try to mark `target/scala-2.11/src_managed/slick/` this as **Sources Root**. like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also generate source file with the code below (example for MySql) :

```
slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator.main(
  Array("slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:33000/MyDB?useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true", 
      "ABSOLUTE_PATH_FOR_FILE", "com.mypackage", "USER","PASS"))
```